# cakephp pagination with count issue

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0, pagination

I have written below code in my `controller` action.

```
$this->paginate['Tag'] = array(
            'fields' => array('COUNT(tag_id) AS numbers', 'tag', 'slug'),
            'limit' => 50,
            'order' => 'numbers desc',
            'recursive' => 2,
            'group' => array('tag'),
        );
$tags = $this->paginate('Tag', array('not' => array('site_id' => NULL), 'tag !=' => ''));
```

And written below code in the `.ctp` file.

```
<div class="row section">
    <div class="col col_16 pagination">
        <h3>Tags</h3>
        <?php
        foreach ($tags as $key => $tag) {
            echo '<span>' . $this->Html->link($tag['Tag']['tag'] . ' (' . $tag[0]['numbers'] . ')', '/tags/' . $tag['Tag']['slug']) . '</span>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col col_16 pagination">
        <?php
        echo $this->Paginator->first('First', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));
        echo $this->Paginator->prev('Previous', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));
        echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => ''));
        echo $this->Paginator->next('Next', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));
        echo $this->Paginator->last('Last', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col col_16 pagination">
        <h5 class="margin0Px">
            <?php
            echo $this->Paginator->counter(array(
                'format' => __('Page %page% of %pages%, showing %current% out of %count% total, starting on %start%, ending on %end%.', true)
            ));
            ?>
        </h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

Getting false result in view `$this->Paginator`.

What is the issue here? I am not getting any idea. Pls help.

Comment: Better that posting the .ctp would be posting the results of tags variable, if anything - the CTP really doesn't matter.  (btw, did you SET the variable?:  $this->set('tags', $tags);

Answer (score 0):

Does you controller define the `helpers` variable? If it doesn't the `Paginator` helper is included by default. If it does you have to remember to include it yourself.

Documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1096/Using-Helpers

Comment: there is no need to add it in helpers. If I remove COUNT(tag_id) AS numbers from fields and 'group' => array('tag'), it works fine.